How to start Wayland session on remote machine's monitor?
Take some machine, which has been logged into on tty1 and left with no graphical display server running.
Is there any way, via SSH, to remotely start a Wayland session (for example, Sway) on the machine's physical monitor? I want to exactly replicate the behavior of having typed sway into tty1.
This particular machine is using OpenRC.

AFAIK it is possible to start sway on a specific logged in tty with systemd-run --user by using XDG_SESSION_ID. While you can run something like bash -lc sway instead of just sway to make it even closer to typing in sway on the tty, it's still not really an "exact replicate" though. (And it might be possible to perform "typing" remotely by e.g. writing to some dev node, idk. Wonder if tmux could help as well.)

(Actually, if the seat has only one session, you may not even need to leverage the env var. And you can find out the value you need with loginctl.)
